# Inserting two strings with the cursor in the middle of the two strings with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to create a text editor. Users can insert html code there. There is a toolbar. When user clicks 'Add Code' button, I want that a **<code></code>** text will be inserted with the cursor at the middle of start and end tag.

I have got the following code to insert any text at the cursor position :

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId,text) {
var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
var strPos = 0;
var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
if (br == "ie") { 
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
}
else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
txtarea.value=front+text+back;
strPos = strPos + text.length;
if (br == "ie") { 
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
    range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
    range.select();
}
else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
}
txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

With this code my desired **<code></code>** is inserted before the cursor. Is there any way to use the code to achieve the following :

*<code>* + Cursor + *</code>*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Since your function already moves the caret to the end of the inserted string, you just need to move it back by a few characters (7 in this case). I'd modify the function to include a param to it to specify the number of characters I want to move the caret back by.

```
 function insertAtCaret(areaId, text, caretOffset) {
```

Then change the part where you calculate the caret position to

```
strPos = strPos + text.length + caretOffset;
```

And when you call your function, do it like so:

```
insertAtCaret('my-textarea', '<code></code>', -7);
```

It should work. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqgQWW) to demonstrate.

Of course, you may or may not want to enhance it with more robust checks, like ensuring that `caretOffset` is always negative, or that the max number of characters it moves the caret back by is the number of characters in the added text.

Comment: But in internet explorer the code is behaving differenly. When the <code></code> is inserted first time the cursor is at the end. Then after inserting it again moves the cursor to the middle. Why?

Comment: I probably found the problem. When the textarea has a placeholder IE is behaving differently.

Edit your Codepen code. Add a placeholder to the textarea. Click on the 'insert code' button. Select the text and delete it. Then again click on the button. See it.

Comment: I suspect it's because of an IE bug that doesn't calculate caret position correctly with blank lines. This is a separate issue, and I believe it can be solved. In any case, I think you shouldn't be doing "feature detection" and "polyfilling" within your methods anyway. I recommend using a polyfill for selection, and then focus on application logic in your methods, rather than cross-browser compatibility issues.